# jQuery validation and client side events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

The code in question: http://jsfiddle.net/3wfYs/1/

Im having some trouble here (validation). When picking a service user (the lower table), the first checkbox in the first table (long list of checkboxes) should also be checked. And the checkboxlist has validation rules in place which say that atleast one has to be checked. However, when selecting the checkbox through code from the "click" event on the serviceuser checkbox, the form doesnt revalidate. How can I achieve this? And also, I feel I'm doing this the hard way, any better way of doing all this?

Found the solution: After manipulating the form, I had to revalidate the form (which was what i was looking for) and this is done by running .valid(). So I ended up doing this:

```
$("#PasswordForm").valid();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because the 'PC-pålogging' checkbox which you automatically check,  is also disabled. It is therefore removed from any validation checks as disabled elements are not passed in POST requests.

If you remove the `.attr("disabled", "disabled")` line from the service user click handler it should work, although you may need to write some more logic to deselct the user service checkbox if the 'PC-pålogging' is deselected.

Comment: That doesnt matter to the validation script, as the checkboxes are still being marked as "error". I want the validation to update without the user having to press submit again to revalidate. Also if you remove the "disabled" parts from the javascript and click on the "pc-pålogging" (while it is checked by serviceuser) it removes the checked mark, and removes the errors (which is opposite of what it should do)